# Cross database select postgresql (dblink )

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I run a stored procedure from database1 - sp1, using dblink, join to another stored procedure - sp2, from database2 something to get the output data where price.sp1 != price.sq2.

Something like this:

```
select * 
from sq1 
inner join dblink('dbname=name', 'select * from sq2') 
where price.sp1 != price.sq2
```

I need this so that if the data of the "price" column (table1) of database1 differs from the data of the "price"(table2) of database2 column, get this mismatched data.

I tried to do something like this but I get an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
> LINE 1: ... inner join dblink('dbname=paymentdb', 'select * from sq2')
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 78

These two databases have different names, but they have the same api and port

Stored procedure 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql2 
( IN Name character varying
, IN InStatus character varying
, OUT Date timestamp without time zone
, OUT Price numeric
, OUT Status character varying
, OUT Service integer
, OUT Agent bigint
, OUT Identifier character varying
)
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT pp.created_dt AS "Date", 
       pp.priceAS "Price", 
       pp.status_id AS "Status", 
       pp.service_id AS "Service", 
       pp.agent_id AS "Agent", 
       pp.external_id AS "Identifier"
  FROM payments AS pp
 WHERE pp.service_id IN (009, 010) 

   AND pp.created_dt::date = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' day)::date
   AND pp.status_id = 'SUCCESS'; 
END ;
$$
```

Stored procedure 2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql1 
( IN Name character varying
, IN InStatus character varying
, OUT Date character varying
, OUT Timee time without time zone
, OUT Initiator character varying
, OUT Service character varying
, OUT Price numeric
, OUT Status character varying
, OUT Props character varying
, OUT Identifier character varying
, OUT External_status character varying
)
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT pp.id, 
       TO_CHAR(pp.created_dt::date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') AS "Date", 
       CAST(pp.created_dt AS time(0)) AS "Timee", 
       au.username AS "Initiator", 
       ss.name AS "Service", 
       pp.price AS "Price", 
       REPLACE(pp.status, 'SUCCESS', 'Good') AS "Status", 
       pp.account AS "Props", 
       pp.external_id AS "Identifier", 
       COALESCE(pp.external_status, null, 'Status') AS "External_status"
  FROM payments_pay AS pp
 INNER JOIN auth_user AS au ON au.id = pp.creator_id
 INNER JOIN services_service AS ss ON ss.id = pp.service_id
 WHERE pp.created_dt::date = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' day)::date
                
   AND ss.name IN ('Some name', 'Some name') AND pp.status = 'SUCCESS';
   END;
   $$
```

Comment: If you need that a lot, a foreign table (through a foreign data wrapper) will be much easier to handle (and probably faster as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html)

> The function returns the row(s) produced by the query. Since dblink
> can be used with any query, it is declared to return record, rather
> than specifying any particular set of columns. This means that you
> must specify the expected set of columns in the calling query —
> otherwise PostgreSQL would not know what to expect.

Also looks like your column references are erroneously reversed, must be TableAlias.ColumnName

```
select * 
from sq1 
inner join dblink('dbname=name', 'select * from sq2') sq2(..your columns here including price..) 
  on ..your join criteria here..
where sq1.price != sq2.price
```

Comment: select * 
from sq1 
inner join dblink('dbname=baseName', 'select * from sq2') sq2(created_dt, price, status_id) 
  on sq1.id = sq2.external_id
where sq1.price!= sq2.price

Comment: I tried to do so. But I'm getting an error: ERROR:  relation "sq1" does not exist
LINE 2: from sq1 
             ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 16

Comment: We hardly can guess what is the real table you want instead of `sq1`.

Comment: I added my question